# Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field using get_queryset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Sorry is this is basic but I'm new at this

I am attempting to take the captured group from a url in the template, (the primary key of the story model) and then use that to filter the correct posts from the Post datbase, which it has a one(story) to many(Post) relationship with. I based the code of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

But when I run it, I get the error:

```
FieldError at /story/1/
Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: body, id, title, work, work_id
```

My code:

```
#views
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from . models import Post, Story

class StoryListView(ListView):
    model = Story
    template_name = 'home.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'story_overview.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.work_id=get_object_or_404(Post, name=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Post.objects.filter(work_id=self.work_id)
#urls
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.StoryListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('story/<int:pk>/', views.PostListView.as_view(),   name='story_overview'),
]

#templates/home.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in object_list %}
    <h2><a href="{% url 'story_overview' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %} 

#models
from django.db import models

class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1500, default= "Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default= "Title")
    work = models.ForeignKey(Story,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter using `work_id` then you should use the integer.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(work_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

If you want to fetch the `Story` instance then you should call `get_object_or_404` with `Story`, and filter on the `pk` field instead of `name`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.work=get_object_or_404(Story, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return Post.objects.filter(work=self.work)
```

Note I've renamed `work_id` to `work` because it's a model instance, not an id.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get object from Post() model using name field. Is name field present in your Post() model?

Instead of doing this

```
self.work_id=get_object_or_404(Post, name=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Do this

```
self.work_id=get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Hope it helps!